# DocuSign API - How do I generate a ReviewDocument link

Tags: docusignapi

So we are having issues where our customers are not getting DocuSign emails.  The emails are being flagged as SPAM, and this is creating problems for us.

We are thinking of just sending our own emails.

To do that, I would need to build the url that DocuSign sends out, so that people can click on it.  Here is the format that DocuSign uses.

/Member/EmailStart.aspx?a=&acct=&er=

Where do I get the 'a' and 'acct' values?

I did find the 'er in the Signers of envelopesApi.ListRecipients

I assume that 'acct' somehow ties to my account, but I can't find that guid in my account anywhere?

Where do I get the 'a' and 'acct' from?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible for you to construct the URL that DocuSign sends out, such that a recipient can use that URL to initiate their signing session. The way to achieve your goal (i.e., send your own emails to recipients rather than DocuSign sending the emails) is by using what DocuSign refers to as "Embedded/Captive" signing. Here's a description of that process:

1) Create the envelope by issuing a `Create Envelope` API request, and specify the `ClientUserId` property for each recipient. The presence of the `ClientUserId` property tells DocuSign not to send emails to recipients (so that you can do it yourself).

2) Send the recipient(s) an email which contains a link that leads them to a web page that you build -- and instructions for them to click that link to launch their Envelope ***whenever they are ready to review/sign the document(s)***. (The link URL would need to contain some sort of querystring parameters that your web page could use to identify the Envelope and Recipient.)

3) Design your web page such that when it receives an inbound request (as it would when the recipient clicks the link in the email you send them), it uses the information in the querystring parameters to identify the Envelope and Recipient, then issues a `CreateRecipientView` request to retrieve the URL that will launch that recipient's signing session, and finally, automatically redirects the user to the URL that the CreateRecipientView response returns, thereby opening the Envelope for the recipient to review/sign/submit. Note that the URL that the `CreateRecipientView` request returns is a short-lived URL that will time out in just a few minutes (5 minutes, I believe) -- that's why you don't want to issue this request to retrieve the URL until the recipient is actually ready to view the Envelope.

By following a process like this, you're able to craft/send the email that recipient(s) receive (instead of relying upon DocuSign to do so), and can ensure that you're only retrieving the envelope URL whenever the user has indicated that they're ready to sign (thereby avoiding the potential of the short-lived link expiring before it's used).

(Search the DocuSign API documentation or Stack Overflow for "Embedded Signing" or "Captive Signing" and you'll find lots of info about this scenario.)

Comment: Thank you.  I never thought of doing it this way, this is a great idea.  I haven't tried it yet, but I'm going to start working on this.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign spends a lot of effort on its emails so they're not marked spam. If the emails are being marked spam, please contact DocuSign Customer Service for help. They will escalate to the engineering group for analysis of the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: I did, and they basically said it's not their problem.  So I am going to try to recreate their email, and send it myself.